# R creating two-by-two table for chisq.test

Tags: r, chi-squared

```
library(dslabs)
data("research_funding_rates")
research_funding_rates
```

"Construct a two-by-two table of gender (men/women) by award status (awarded/not) using the total numbers across all disciplines."

I have tried

```
r_s <- research_funding_rates %>% mutate(not_awarded_men = applications_men - awards_men, not_awarded_women = applications_women - awards_women)
r_s_t <- r_s %>% summarise(not_awarded_women = sum(not_awarded_women), awarded_women = sum(awards_women), not_awarded_men = sum(not_awarded_men), awarded_men = sum(awards_men))
colnames(r_s_t) <- NULL
t <- as.table(matrix(r_s_t, ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE))
chisq.test(t)
```

But this gives the error
error in sum(x), invalid type list

str(t) returns
List of 4
$ : num 1011
$ : num 1345
$ : num 177
$ : num 29
instead of table

whereas this simple example

```
sex_pet <- matrix(c(19, 34, 22, 26, 28, 6),nrow=2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames =list(sex=c("Male", "Female"), pet=c("Cats", "Dogs", "Other")))
sex_pet_table <- as.table(sex_pet)
chisq.test(sex_pet_table)
```

works as expected. How can I get a 2x2 table from the data above to perform a chisq.test??

Thanks,

Hans

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `r_s_t` is a `data.frame`. You should convert it to a vector first, then pass it into matrix.

```r
t <- matrix(as.numeric(r_s_t), ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)
t
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,] 1011  177
#> [2,] 1345  290
chisq.test(t)
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  t
#> X-squared = 3.8111, df = 1, p-value = 0.05091
```